# How to pass value to [disabled] function in Angular 8.2.9

Tags: angular

In Angular 8.2.9, how can I pass parameters to the [disabled] attribute? (Is it called an attribute?)

In this example, I want to pass "John" to isDisabled() via the HTML Input Id value.

```
<input type="text" id="John" [(ngModel)]="txtProjectCode" [disabled]="isDisabled(id)" />
```

Alternatively, I also tried using Template Reference Var, but error at runtime says cannot assign: "Uncaught Error: Cannot assign to a reference or variable!"

```
<input type="text" #John [(ngModel)]="txtProjectCode" [disabled]="isDisabled(John)" />
```

I just want a way to identify who is calling isDisabled() in this case.

Generally, can I use any function with any function signature for all such handlers or are the function signature fixed by Angular definition? Where can I find the list of function signature for each attribute?

I tried to search "disabled" in http://angular.io website but the search result is not useful at all. The closest I find is https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax but it doesn't explain how it works.

EDIT 1:
For those who need to see my isDiabled(), here it is, although I don't think it of relevance to this question.

```
public isDisabled(htmlId:any):boolean {
    console.log(htmlId);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Please ask if you think "unclear what you're asking" before eagerly voting to close. It is unclear why it is unclear to you if you don't leave a comment. Thanks.

Comment: Your second example should (kinda) work. IsDisabled should be a function inside your component. Note that ‘John’ gives you the entire input element so use John.value if that is what you want to check..Besides that pointer, using function calls from your template this way is not recommended for performance reasons..

Comment: @MikeOne Thank you. I already have isDisabled() in my component. The question is, how to pass the value to the isDisabled function in general, including the HTML element and/or its attribute values, or any other custom values, or even multiple parameters values?

Comment: What does your `isDisabled` method look like? What (type and value) is it supposed to take as argument? What happens when you execute that code? An expression is an expression is an expression. Whether you use it to populate the `disabled` property or to do anything else doesn't change how it's evaluated. If you want to pass the string "John", then pass the string "John": `[disabled]="isDisabled('John')"`.

Comment: Guys, can you please explain why the question is unclear? As stated clearly in the title and further at the top of the question: "In this example, I want to pass "John" to isDisabled() via the HTML Input Id value." Why is it still unclear?

Comment: I repeat: If you want to pass the string "John", then pass the string "John": `[disabled]="isDisabled('John')"`.

Comment: @JBNizet I don't want to pass the string "John". I want to pass the HTML Input Id.

Comment: And the input ID is the string "John". You seem to think backwards: the view is populated from the model, not vice-versa. You want to pass a view value to a method of the model. It's possible, but it's backward. if you want both the ID attribute and the value passed to isDisabled() to have the same value, then define a property in the component, and use it in the view: `<input [id]="someVariable" [disabled]="isDisabled(someVariable)"`. What's the point of passing the ID of an input to the method however? That's what is very unclear in your question: how is the ID relevant?

Comment: @JBNizet "What's the point of passing the ID of an input to the method?" -- this is irrelevant to the question. So I did not include in my question. All I am asking is how it can be done, I was expecting an answer (which you have given, so you can put in the answers) or "No, it cannot be done."

Comment: It **can** be done. But doing it is, most probably, an extremely bad idea because it shows that you're not using the framework as you should, and haven't understood its fundamental principles. You keep saying it's irrelevant, but you're asking more experienced people, and those tell you that it **is** relevant. So, if you really want to learn, explain why you want to do that. Tell which concrete problem you want to solve. There's most probably a better solution than the one you chose.

Comment: @JBNizet I am just explaining why I didn't add my use case in my original question. I do accept that it is relevant if the more experienced tells me and I will add more details to the respective comments in the answer section or edit my question. Therefore I hope people can put comments to explain what more info is needed before eagerly trying to close the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your HTML.

```
<input type="text" #John  id="MYID" [(ngModel)]="txtProjectCode" [disabled]="isDisabled(John)" />
```

in Your component.

```
  isDisabled(je) {
    console.log(je.type);
    console.log(je.value);
    console.log(je.id);
  }
```

But what exactly you want to do? because Angular provide betters ways to get a reference of your HTML tags

Comment: Thank you. Let me try this again because I am getting an error at runtime in the console when I do this. "Uncaught Error: Cannot assign to a reference or variable!"

Comment: anotehr thing is wrong, let me see more of your code and see a functional example here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ee7drg.